# How to use string.Format for @ref

Tags: c#, blazor

I have many dropdown items in my real code. Shown a sample below. I am rewriting the code to reduce the number of lines, so that it is easier to read and maintain.

```
@if (ItemTest.Contains("One"))
{
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <button @ref="_btn1" class="item" id="0" @onclick=Open1>One</button>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <button @ref="_btn2" class="item" id="1" @onclick=Open2>Two</button>
    </li>
} 
                            
@if (ItemTest.Contains("Two"))
{
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <button @ref="_btn3" class="item" id="3" @onclick=Open3>Three</button>
    </li>
    
}
```

Comment: @ref is a reference to the component in C# it's not an Id. You cannot change it like that. The @ref will assign a reference to the field/property specified.  The @ref field should be of type `ElementReference` or the type of a component referenced.

Comment: Thank you. I do assign like this:  private ElementReference _btn1Ref; private ElementReference _btn2Ref; etc.. I want to refactor the code to make it easier to maintain.  Is there any other way to make this "_btn1Ref" take dynamic numbers in the for loop.

Comment: @Sarahrb it is supposed to be variable names, therefore adding the number dynamically in the name does not seem necessary. However, I guess you should be able to store those references in a list or dictionary.

Comment: Ok, I will try storing them as a list. Thank you.

Comment: I tried as suggested, all seems good. But I get error when I click on a button, for eg: on click of button "two", it says OpenDialog2 is not defined.... similarly on click of button "three", OpenDialog3 is not defined. May I know where I am going wrong. Please see code above. Thanks

Comment: @Sarahrb when using for loops create a copy of the index variable. `var iCopy = i;` and use that to assign the references. Without this step all the references will probably point to the same component/element. It's a known issue with the for loop pattern. `someArray[iCopy]`

Comment: @BrianParker thank you for the input. I tried, it still says the same error "OpenDialog2 is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store your references in a list and use them this way:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@for(int i=0; i < btnReferences.Count; i++)
{
  var iCopy = i;
  <button @ref="btnReferences[iCopy]" @onclick="(async () => await TestRef(iCopy))"></button>
}

@code{
  private List<ElementReference> btnReferences = new List<ElementReference>();

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      btnReferences.Add(new ElementReference());
    }
  }

  public async Task TestRef(int i)
  {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", testref[i].Id);
  }
}
```

As Brian already said, `@ref` needs `ElementReference` (or component type): `string` is not a valid type. `@onclick` meets the same issues.

Comment: Would appreciate if you have any suggestion on this... Assume, NavItem satisfies both PH1 and PH2. But btnReferences[i] returns "__internalId : null" at times for some of the items. May I know what is wrong. I have added my new code above.

Comment: @Sarahrb Avoid mutating questions because answers may not be relevant anymore. Please rollback your question as it was and ask a new one for the new issue.

Comment: Would appreciate if you have any suggestion on this. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75066726/buttonreference-returns-internalid-as-null